# Is there a way to optimize, and possibly automatize this ItemPickup script?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

is there a way to optimize this part of my script?:

```
    public TextMeshProUGUI interactionText;
    public TextMeshProUGUI pickedUpText;
    public GameObject InteractionTextShow;
    public GameObject PickedUpTextShow;
```

If possible I wish to assign the Text, and TextShow automatically in this script. The interactionText is for assigning the name of the object to the name, and the interactionTextShow, is for showing the text. Here's the full code.

```
public class ItemPickup : Interactable
{
    public TextMeshProUGUI interactionText;
    public TextMeshProUGUI pickedUpText;
    public GameObject InteractionTextShow;
    public GameObject PickedUpTextShow;
    [SerializeField] private Item item;

    public override void OnFocus()
    {
        print("Press E to pick up " + item.Name);

        interactionText.text = item.Name;
        InteractionTextShow.SetActive(true);
    }

    public override void OnInteract()
    {
        PickUp(); 
        PickedUpTextShow.SetActive(true);
        pickedUpText.text = "Picked up: " + item.Name;
    }



    public override void OnLoseFocus()
    {
        InteractionTextShow.SetActive(false);
        print("Lost focus with " + item.Name);
    }
    void PickUp()
    {

        print("Picked up: " + item.Name);
        bool wasPickedUp = Inventory.instance.Add(item);
        if (wasPickedUp)
        {
            Destroy(gameObject);
            InteractionTextShow.SetActive(false);
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to delete the TextMeshProUGUI, and assign something like interactionTextShow.TextMeshProUGUI.text = item.Name, but it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

The way I normally assign scripts procedurally (Through code) is by instantiating an empty object like this:

```
GameObject object = Instantiate(new GameObject);
```

and then assigning a script to it like this:

```
object.AddComponent\<MyScript>();
```

Comment: also where it says "MyScript", replace it with "Text" to assign a Text component to the gameObject